# DFP (DoubleClick) ad unit not being backfilled with AdSense on Android

Tags: android, ads, adsense

I am successfully using DFP for my website, and the ads I don't manage to sell directly are back-filled with AdSense. This works great.

Now I have developed an Android app containing a new ad-unit. I want to offer this new ad-unit (320x50) via DFP, so I created a new 320x50 ad unit in DFP. I "generated tags" to get the correct AdUnitID for my Android ad, and I can indeed see the house ads I created to fill 10% of the inventory in the app.  So the app is connected to DFP, right?

The problem is, AdSense ads are never served and I see the message "No fill from ad server." in ADB.  But I am confused, because the DFP ad-unit is configured to display AdSense.

Does anyone know why this is?  I have waited a couple of days for all the DFP changes to propagate, but still nothing.  I have checked all over Stackoverflow and Google, and I'm slowly pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else out there with the same problem, I found a solution.  For some crazy reason, DFP ad-units are not automatically backfilled with AdSense, even though both products are from Google. This is by design(!).

The workaround is to create an AdMob ad, and create a new DFP line item with a single creative of type "AdMob" linked to your AdMob ad. So then DFP will refuse to serve AdSense, but instead will serve AdMob which serves AdSense for you anyway.